# Analog vs Digital Examples

Tags: homework

Beginner question, but I am confused on how to tell between analog and digital and applying it to everyday life. For example, what would school grades be, or a photo from kodak film? I know analog is supposed to be continuous but how do I apply it to these scenarios?

Comment: Is a grade continuous? Can you get anything between A and  B?  Is the image on a film continuous? You can look at two planes. Is the color range continuous? Is the image itself continuous? For the first I would say it is pretty continuous. For the second - not really, as films are usually granulated.

Comment: 35% is analog. Fail is digital.

Comment: Digital is just a special case of analog.

Comment: @JohnD not quite. It is implemented with a special type of analog circuitry, but the "digital" part is mathematically a level above the implementation.

Comment: @Trevor You mean that *discrete* math is the whole sub-field of mathematics. And pretty important one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. exactly

Comment: @JohnD, In a different way to look at it---more useful to some people---digital is not like analog at all.  Digital computing is an _abstraction_.  The physical embodiment of a digital computer is wires and transistors that all carry analog signals, but when you take the description of how the machine works up to the "digital" level you altogether stop talking about voltages and currents (i.e., the "analog" stuff), and you talk instead about the boolean values and the numbers---the "digital" stuff---that those voltages and currents represent.

Comment: @Trevor you and James took my comment too seriously, it's just something us analog guys say to annoy the digital guys.  Agreed about digital logic/computing being a mathematical abstraction.  However, you can argue that nothing is analog when you look at things at the quantum level....

Comment: @JohnD :) yup when you come to math things can get a little abstract. Hence I said..not quite.

Comment: @JohnD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law

Comment: @JohnD, actually, if you dig deeper and get into quantum levels, analogue is a special case of digital :D

Comment: Technically speaking, what you're referring to is called discrete vs continuous, while digital and analogue can only be applied to signals (e.g. digital is a discrete signal and analogue is continuous). People often (read: always) use these terms interchangeably, but they are not exactly the same thing (like I said, digital and analogue only apply to signals of some sort)

Comment: actually **all digital signals are always continuous analog signals** but we throw away all the information bandwidth of this logic signal in exchange for an extremely low error rate.  We only choose to decimate the analog signal with 1 bit of information at some instant of time.  Even Quantum Physics is Analog.

Answer (score 4):

Digital is anything that can be analysed with logic or represented without loss of information by a finite number of discrete values.

For example:

Your test score, e.g. 35.333%, is an analog quantity. It can be any value between 0 and 100 with any mathematical fraction.

"Fail" however is a digital quantity since it is either true or it is false.

You can however, convert analog into a digital scale.

By assigning a number of "bits" of true and false states, you can logically give each combination of those "bits" an analog "weight". At that point you can have a circuit, named an Analog-TO-Digital convertor, that examines the analog data and selects the appropriate bit combination that most closely matches the weight you assigned to it.

If you do that repeatedly either by time, for something like you favourite radio tune, or by X-Y location for an image, you can store a digitized equivalent of that track or picture.

Note though information is lost in the process of conversion to digital. Since there are a finite number of combinations of the bits, there are only a finite number of values you can store. As such all the original analog values that were in between the weights you assigned are rounded to the nearest value and you can no longer reconstruct the exact original value.

If you digitized your test score so the digital weights were 1% each, then it would not matter if your score was 35% or actually 34.5%. It would be stored as 35% in either case. The information that you actually got a little less than 35% would be lost.

Note, as James pointed out in the comments, your Grade is a quantized value based on your cumulative scores. As such you get B, B+ etc. which is a digital, or quantized, representation of your actual results.

**Addition.**

Another way to think about digital is to go back a couple of millenia to basics.

Can you accurately represent the quantity using fingers, "digits"?

[image]

Look at the four fingers on your left hand. Bend a couple down. There are 16 combinations of bent versus straight fingers. Add more hands, and you have more combinations. *(Nerdy entertainment: Count from 0 to 15 in binary with just those four fingers..)*

If ALL the states of the quantity you are thinking about can be encoded into combinations of a finite number of straight or bent fingers with 100% accuracy, no loss of information, then the quantity is digital. Digital = "Can turn it into fingers".

If you need an extra third of a finger.. it is not.

Comment: 35% is a _number_ (i.e., it's already digital).  If you choose to report a student's grades as whole multiples of 1%, you're not digitizing the grades, you're _quantizing_ the grades.  An analog report card would not have numbers on it:  It might, for example have a bar graph where the lengths of the bars were _analogs_ of the student's performance in different subjects.

Comment: @jameslarge arguably yes, until you add the fraction. Quantizing and digitizing is so close as to be synonymous. But good addition.

Comment: @jameslarge and you are right grades, are already encoded. So I changed it to test score, which is what I was really thinking.

Comment: "Your test score may be 35.333%, that is an analog quantity" I disagree. You've represented it with a fixed number of digits, it's therefore digital. If test scores can range from .001 to 100.000 in steps of 0.001 they're digital even if they're not integers.

Comment: @Finbarr the fact that this score is 35.333 which is supposed to represent a thid, does not preclude it from being any number of any accuracy. Just because a particular score can be represented digitally does not indicate that the quantity score itself can.

Comment: But 35.333 is a quantized representation of a third... I'm only going by your definition, it can be represented by fingers. Even a third of a finger is still digital if you allow it in your set of digital values.

Comment: @Finbarr you are missing the point 35.333 may be a quantized representation of a particular score, but score itself is not digital. It would ONLY be digital if there were a unique number of different scores.

Comment: I know what you're trying to say, but the reality is that there ARE only a fixed number of different grade scores. Even if fractional values were awarded, which is rare enough, they'd probably be chosen from a very limited set - tenths, quarters or thirds. Probably just halves.

Comment: Rational numbers (which is what I think you mean by "fractions") are TRIVIAL to represent digitally as two binary integers representing the numerator and denominator, ie. 35 and one third  becomes 106 and 3 (106/3 = 35.333333333333333...)
So lets say your teacher gives you an irrational score of say pi or e? Well in fact any number that can be defined and calculated can be given a digital representation - computer algebra systems represent numbers and other mathematical objects with data structures.

Comment: Fractions don't assign "analog-ness" to a number, it's still an exact number, represented by digits, therefore digital. An arrow on a dial pointing between 35 and 36 would be analog. The number X is NEVER analog. The *grading scale* might be analog, but once you give a number, you've given digits, therefore digital.

Comment: @Jasmine ok..so try that with \$\pi\$

Comment: Pi is actually still an exact value. It can't be represented with base 10 digits, but I could write it exactly in some other bases. The point being - a value itself is never analog. Numbers are not analog. Numbers can be represented in an analog way, but the number itself is a damn number.

Comment: @Jasmine we could argue this forever, which would be completely against the point of my answer, however, Pi may be an "exact" number however it can not be written exactly in ANY base. It is the analog ratio of diameter to circumference both of which are also, ultimately, analog.   But you are missing my point anyway. Rounding a non-converging value to a writable number, is quantizing that value, at which point it is indeed no longer analog, but then again, it is not the original exact value either.

Comment: Sure, I agree with that. Minor point though: here is the number pi, written exactly in base-pi... 1.

Comment: @Jasmine lol.. OK I'll give you that one. ;) THough that's really just a count of Pis. Sigh now I am hungry.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking:  Analog and Digital are two different modes of [signal processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_processing).  An analog signal is some measurable quantity (voltage, current, pressure, etc.) that changes over time in such a way that the changes carry *information*.  The word "analog" comes from the same root as ["analogy"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/analogy?s=t).  For example, the value of the voltage produced by a microphone is *analogous to* (or, *an analog of*) the instantaneous sound pressure on the microphone diaphragm.

An analog signal can be [sampled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing))—its value can be captured at periodic intervals in time—and it can be [quantized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing))—it can be limited to a certain number of discrete values.

Once a signal has been sampled and quantized, it can be *digitized* (i.e., it can be turned into a sequence of numbers known as a [digital signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal)).  [Digital signal processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing) are specialized computers, or specialized computer algorithms that modify a digital signal to selectively emphasize or deemphasize specific details of the information that it carries.

---

Any other use of "analog" and "digital" is less formal, and you'll have a hard time finding any authoritative definition of what those words mean outside of the world of signal processing.

Comment: The difference between an analog clock and a digital clock would be an authoritative definition. Hands can be in any position, but the numbers can take only a discrete set of values.

Comment: @Finbarr.  I once attended a school where the clocks only ticked once per minute.  Every minute, the minute hands of all of the clocks would advance with an audible "ka-chunk."  I would argue that those clocks were "analog" because, even though the clock was only capable of displaying one of 720 distinct time values, it was the _position_ of the hands that told the time:  The distance that the hands moved during a given interval was proportional to the length of the interval.  My daughter's new alarm clock, on the other hand, is "digital" because it tells the time by displaying _numbers_.

Comment: I realised that as soon as I looked at the clock on the office wall! For clock read sundial!

Comment: @jameslarge, I've commented on the first answer, then read yours, this is basically what I was trying to say about analogue/digital vs continuous/discrete... Still disagree on the clock part, it's neither digital nor analogue. The clock (or rather the arrow movement) can be discrete (with the audible "ka-chunk") or continuous (with a properly timed motor that turns dials continuously)

Comment: Actually, scrub my comment, I was right first time. I doesn't matter that the second hand jumps once a second - it still goes through an infinite number of values as it goes round, it just doesn't do it a constant rate.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about marks, say you can get any mark from 0-100 including all those decimal point numbers possible in between 0-100. We can call it continous. Talking about school grades, it can take only a value from a defined set of values ( O, A, B..).It is quantized and we can call it discrete. Talking about photos, a photo captured by a digital camera is composed of pixels and each pixel has a definite R,G,B intensity defined by n-bit binary numbers.  Here R,G,B  can take only particular set of binary values (0 to 2^n -1). So the camera can represent only a definite set of colors in its photos. But in real world, infinitely no. of combinations of R,G,B are possible. We can say we live in an analog world. Digital world is just an easy way to represent its various aspects.

Answer (score 1):

**Everything in life is Analog, and probably even Quantum Physics. (pun intended)**

Logic was "invented" by famous Greek Philosphers those who defined the "rules" or Laws of good Logic and bad Logic or fallacies.   Those with lack of awareness will disagree.  We only define Logic by defining rules for accurate thresholds and validating those thresholds to be accurate so that accurate decisions can be made.  We must quantize the noise and minimize it by design.  ( Shannon's Law defines this relationship between error and noise ratios. _

In Electronics we define logic levels by some Analog to Digital Conversion (ADC) but we must choose each threshold wisely and identify all the causes of error.

The same applies to human reasoning True or False. Because there is a grey zone between where noise can cause errors, so we must minimize this error by design, accurate measurements and experience. It applies to colours, sounds, and any physical abuse.  *What does it mean to be True or False, Good or Bad? Nothing is truly black or white unless we predetermine the rules and thresholds.*

--

For TTL binary logic on a 5V supply this threshold is 1.4V +/- 0.6V, so we say <=0.8V is a "0" and >=2.0V is a "1". These thresholds give good immunity to power noise from some stray source to give a high margin for making valid decisions.  The "keepout" or grey zone  in between is always crossed but ensure by design that of our systems will recognize or ignore this transition as we see fit.

This edge detection is like changing our minds based on different feedback or perhaps changing our thresholds for intolerance or tolerance of bias to making better decisions.

Human Reasoning was defined by Logic Rules defined by Aristotle and Plato and is still valid today.  Yet few engineers know that there are **144 rules called Fallacies** which define all the errors in everyday thinking. the most common is from bad assumptions.   But first you must understand that like the Laws of Physics can never be broken, only the assumptions or its application can be wrong.  *Yet everyone knows at least 1 fallacy.* ( Agumentum ad ....} The modern secular legal systems ( not sharia) are based on  "Black's Rules of Law" which are tailored to each society with the fallacies defined by those Greek Philosophers. "Objection your honor" is then followed by "legal grounds" or relating to some fallacy.

How well these  signals or noises are defined in legal words must be asserted and proven to determine if they are valid. ( This is the analog part of reasoning)  Then binary decisions such as **guilty or not guilty** have other constraints to reduce the probability of a bad decision. Such as unanimous jury decisions or majority decisions depending on severity of the issue.  So the legal system is very much "analog" and all about converting it to valid a digital result using evidence, reasoning and the rules of logic for each society.  Many rules are archaic or barbaric and still in effect. Why don't they change them? Good question.

All fax. copies were black and white to reduce the size of the data when modems were slow. The thresholds to convert the photo image or digital print were calibrated according to the reflection of light referenced to some fixed threshold and some spectrum of light with some reflection ratio of colors.

### All measurements in life are analog

(including those captured by digital engineers  and/or quantum physicists. ;) Someone gets to define the conversion factors into quantized levels and these stem from experts in global standards such as NIST.

Probability is an Analog variable often applied to a binary conclusion such as "failure".

Usually everything in life is converted from Analog to Digital and is quantized to some non-linear curve or bell-shaped (Gaussian) curve such as school grades.  These quantization levels are defined by standards with variations adapted by those responsible. Such as Colour Gamma curves for CRT Monitors and LCD displays.

### Digital telephony for voice is quantized globally into 8 bits at a 64 kbps standard rate.

Yet has an effective dynamic range >> 70dB  How? They use a non-linear conversion to match ear response called a A-law or mu-Law CODEC or CODer/DECoder. ( Americans invented A-law technology then Europeans changed it slightly for the ROTW or rest of the world)

### Temperature is another analog to digital conversion (ADC).

About 200 years ago, when a Dutch-German-Polish [**Physicist**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Gabriel_Fahrenheit) defined **0 degree reference** it was based on sea brine with equal parts salt and water  when frozen then boiling.  He had reasons for defining this 0'F and 180'F separation between ice and gas. Unfortunately this later turned to be a poor choice for modern physics by that time America figured it cost too much  to change.  Canada changed to metric when I was young, but then after NAFTA, US goods appeared to be cheaper in $/lb than $/kg so it crept back into the stores along with US gallons for paint.  ***This is another bad example of analog to digital conversion by non-conformists, easily swayed by revenue advantages.***

Not only every life form but every product of man and every conversion of energy is analog. ( potential result by any form of energy. Electrical, magnetic, chemical, nuclear, thermal, gravitational etc

How many examples can you think of?

**Even logic can be considered as Analog** depending on the "reasonable" probability of error.

Logic was "invented" by famous Greek Philosophers,  who defined the "rules" or Laws of good Logic and bad Logic or fallacies.  It all starts with Facts and the assumptions based on these facts to be true.  To add unfair bias or illogical thinking is called a fallacy.  It's just bad human reasoning and it happens every day , even by politicians. But then **bad is also a quantifying threshold word for which we have another set of rules. bad for the individual, the family, the society , the region, the nation, the planet.  Ultimately it comes down to Human Values, Ethics ( and Logic)  how you define these and why they need updating.

**Aristotle defined all the Rules of BAD LOGIC**
, and Plato refined some of them later.   Much later logic was applied to math then electronics all simple terms derived from Aristotle's Logic; such as **de Morgan's Rules.**

Logic may be binary, duobinary (+/-,0) or tertiary or differential or any "quantized" characteristic. still have analog characteristics which affects the probability of that digital value being correct or accurate or is affected by the bias threshold we choose for discriminating what digital value we choose.

Perhaps there are questions in Life that are **not binary** ( yes/no), such as does God exist? But then the Laws of Logic are irrefutable. So if everything cannot be proven, then we must have a Belief System based on Values and Ethics to utilize our untapped powers and have safer rules to live by.

Perhaps atomic properties are the only things in nature which can be truly lossless ( Energy can neither be lost nor destroyed) and also pure logical  ( Feynman atomic equations, but that is a deeper question.

Comment: Now is that a logical argument or an analogous one. ;)

Comment: I once consulted for a fingerprint security company that thought they invented "analogic"  It was a fallacy and they went from zero to 1B$ in stock value to zero.

Comment: Quantum Physics is discreet.  One problem that was explicitly resolved by quantification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe

Comment: Discrete, yes but even Feyman's QED equations are defined by probabilities based on energy levels of electrons and photons

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 exactly. At least with our current knowledge, you barely can quantize *some* physical values; IMO, as long as the probability distributions can be continuous, the fact that we observe some physically strictly quantized values is barely important in real life; not many of us need to count single atomic decays or trace single electons - and even for me, during my college course, it was more fun than important...

Answer (score 0):

You can think in terms of discrete and continuous values. So, for your example, your grades are A-F. Your grade can only be one of those values, nothing in between, so it's discrete. We call something digital when there are only two (di) discrete values, and in electronics usually denote those 1 and 0 (on or off).

An old film photo is analog, because the colour can be anything, it's not set to certain values. Another example is temperature, it can be anywhere from really cold to really hot, there's no value it can't take.

Comment: *there's no value it can't take* - except that it's range is lower-bounded by 0 Kelvin.

Comment: @EugeneSh. True, if you're being pedantic and not answering at a reasonable level for the Q.

Comment: What if the grades are using a 4.0 scale rather than letter grades? So letter grades fold a range of grade values into a single letter grade. On the other hand there is a limit for 4.0 scale grades, say two decimal places. So perhaps those are discrete and digital after all?

Comment: @RichardChambers After all the grades are limited by the means they are written on. I doubt someone will give a grade which would look something like \$\sqrt{\pi}\$... And today it is mostly computerized, so definitely is stored digitally.

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, if you artificially limit your precision by way of number of digits, it's inherently discrete. Your discrete description closer approximates the real (analog) value the more significant digits you have.

Answer (score 0):

Data will be 1(ex.5Volts) or 0(Ground) always and usually digital data contains 8, 10 or 12 bits to mean a value between 0 or 1. Its resolution will be Voltage Level/2^Bit. But analog data can have any(infinite resolution) value between 1 and 0 at same time. Analog datas don't have bits to mean a value between 0 or 1.

We always apply proportion to get those datas to understand in our sense.

To apply your scenarios, you can use this algorithm(or formula whatever you say) to your grades: " 100*( Your Grade/Avarage Grade ) ".

For a photo all colours are integrate of blue, green and red. Intensity is voltage level of those colours. In case of maximum voltage level for these 3 colours you would see whit and in case of minimum(ground or zero volt) voltage level you would see black. It's called RGB Technology.